# Python ReadLine() for CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, readline

How do I find an empty line, in a CSV file, that looks like this `',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\n'` with python's ReadLine().

I want to write something like this:

```
file = 'file.csv'

f = open(file, mode='r', encoding='utf8')

while f.readline() != '\n' or f.readline() != ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\n':
    pass

df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None)

f.close()
```

The `or f.readline() != ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\n':` is not identifying the line that looks like this `',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\n'`

I felt that would work when running `f.readline()` manually in my notebook over and over until I got to the first "blank" line. Then the output looked like `',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\n'` and I thought surely that would pick it up. Needless to say it did not.

Comment: What does the top of your CSV look like, with all the empty lines and `,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,` lines?

Comment: @ZachYoung The file has a few lines at the top. Those lines contain strings, then the end of each line contains commas ```,,,,,,,,,,,,,```, random. You'll see I have accepted the answer but I still don't understand these additional commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `f.readline()` twice in that `or` statement, you're actually processing two lines. Try storing it as a variable before evaluating it, so you only process one line at a time. Does this do what you need?:

```
import pandas as pd

file = 'file.csv'

f = open(file, mode='r', encoding='utf8')

if_continue = True
while if_continue:
    current_line = f.readline()
    print(f"current_line is {current_line}")
    if current_line != '\n' or current_line !=  ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,':
        if_continue = False
        print("Exiting while loop")

df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None)

f.close()
```

Comment: hey thanks! unfortunately no. ```while f.readline() not in (',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\n', '\n'):``` solves the problem. I did learn about this from your response though! It led to new questions!